Numerical values for the volume of qubits
This paper mentions the volume of qubit in equation (9) given by:
$$Q_0=U*C_1*T_o*n_p^{(2/3)}*(v_q)^{(2/3)}$$
where

$Q_0$ is the heat entering the chamber
$U$ is the heat transfer coefficient
$C_1$ is a geometric constant. (For a cube, C_1=6; for a
sphere, $C_1=\sqrt{36\pi}$)
$n_p$ is the number of qubits
$v_q$ is the volume required to house a qubit when all connections and other geometric constraints are taken into account.

Are there any numerical values commonly used for $v_q$? Otherwise, is there any approximation that can be used to assess its value roughly?
Unfortunately, this value as well as the value of the power used by a qubit  are not reported in the literature but they are fundamental to calculate the energy consumed by quantum chips.

Hi and welcome on Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add more details? What the equation you mentioned describes for example. In other words, please provide more context to your question.

@MartinVesely I added more details to clarify the context of my question.
